# Connecting Silverlight app to Self hosted WCF service

Tags: wcf, self-hosting

I've created a WCF service that is running on 192.168.0.199:87. The service works without an issue. However, when I create a Silverlight app to consume this service on my dev pc in VS I am getting the cross-domain problem. How am I going to solve this? The service is not an IIS WCF service. I also can't host the WCF service and the Silverlight app on the same port. Silverlight is looking for the clientaccesspolicy.xml on 192.178.0.199:87, in this case, this is the address of my self hosted WCF service.

Any help would be great.

This is my code I don't know if I brew something good.
My app.config file is located here. I think it's an endpoint problem but I am not sure.
http://213.46.36.140/app.config.txt

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication11
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public ServiceHost _host = null;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }      

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _host = new ServiceHost(typeof(WmsStatService));
            _host.Open();
        }
    }

    // Define a service contract.
    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://WindowsFormsApplication11")]
    public interface IWmsStat
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string sayHello(string name);
        [OperationContract, WebGet(UriTemplate = "/clientaccesspolicy.xml")]
        Stream GetSilverlightPolicy();
    }

    public class WmsStatService : IWmsStat
    {
        public string sayHello(string name)
        {
            return "hello there " + name + " nice to meet you!";
        }

        Stream StringToStream(string result)
        {
            WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "application/xml";
            return new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(result));
        }
        public Stream GetSilverlightPolicy()
        {
            // result cointains the clienaccpolicy.xml content.
            //
string result = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
<access-policy>
    <cross-domain-access>
        <policy>
            <allow-from http-request-headers=""*"">
                <domain uri=""*""/>
            </allow-from>
            <grant-to>
                <resource path=""/"" include-subpaths=""true""/>
            </grant-to>
        </policy>
    </cross-domain-access>
</access-policy>";
            return StringToStream(result);
        }
    }
}
```